# clojure namespaces .core file and repl

Tags: clojure, namespaces

A beginners question.

running clojure using lein + emacs + nrepl.

I am slightly confused about the following:

I wish to use the exponent function. This function lives in the following place `clojure.math.numeric-tower`. I add `[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.1"]` to the dependencies and run `lein deps`.

Now is it possible (I'm sure it is possible) to add this to my `.core ns` as follows:

```
(ns learning.core
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))

(def i-know-the-answer
  (math/expt 2 10))
```

now when I try to load (`ctl-x e`) this into the REPL, it throws errors.

`clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: math, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:2)`

do the dependencies need to be loaded into the REPL directly? Can I not just change the source file / recompile it and use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the file with ctrl-c ctrl-l then Switch your repl to the namespace in that file with either

```
(in-ns 'learning.core)
```

Or hit ctrl-c alt-n from the Clojure buffer to switch the repl to the buffer's namespace. You can tell if it worked by looking at the prompt in the repl.

Comment: Just fyi, "In-ns" will not work. It has to be "in-ns". Clojure var names are case-sensitive.